# What was the mineral turbinium being used for?

Tags: total-recall

In the movie Total Recall humans are on Mars mining the exotic mineral turbinium. Was it ever explained in canon what this mineral was being used for?

Comment: ***[TURBO BOOST™](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html)***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's only mentioned in general, to have military application (kind of implied to be space based energy weapon platforms).

**One can imagine that it's some sort of a fuel for an energy generator**, based on the quotes, and the fact that this is how it was intended to be used by original builders - as fuel for a mega-reactor.

However, please keep in mind that in reality, it doesn't matter since it's merely a specific case of [Unobtainium](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Unobtainium) (WARNING: TvTropes link!), there to serve a very specific purpose in driving the plot.

*From screenplay<sup>[1]</sup>:*

> COHAGEN: Absolutely not.  Mars was colonized by the Northern Block at enormous expense. Our entire war effort depends on their turbinium.

... and later

> MARTIAN HUSBAND They just want our turbinium, so they can zap things from space.

*And the reactor quotes:*

> SCIENTIST B (O.S.) The chain reaction could spread to all the turbinium in the crust.

... and

> QUAID (O.S.) It's all one big reactor made out of turbinium.

<sub>[1]: Source: Total Recall (1990) by Ronald Shusett and Dan O'Bannon and Gary Goldman. 
Based on the short story by Philip K. Dick "We Can Remember It For You Wholesale"</sub>

<sub>**Final script, August 22, 1989.**</sub>

Comment: What about the short story?  Does it even mention turbinium?  (I haven't read it.)

Comment: The short story doesn't go into details of what Quail did on Mars, except to say that Interplan don't want it publicised because it would harm their image. The emphasis of the story is very different to the film. Having said that, I enjoyed both. Much like "Do Androids Dream ..." and "Blade Runner".

Answer (score 3):

**Turbinium was used as a *"key component"* of the Northern Bloc's *"space-based"* "*particle beam weapons program"*.**

> The news footage of the Martian Mine episode occupied the large center
> portion of the screen. The newscaster narrated in a mini-screen of his
> own. ". . .an explosion ruptured the geodesic dome over the Pyramid
> Mine, halting the extraction of turbinium ore, key resource of the
> Northern Bloc's particle beam weapons program."
>
> <sub><sup>[Total Recall: Official Film Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/15512)</sup></sub>

and

> Cohaagen knew that whoever controlled the Martian turbinium mines controlled the Northern Bloc, all of the Northern Bloc, not just a few powerful politicians. Without turbinium to fuel their weapons, the Northern Bloc would be forced to surrender.

and

> Turbinium was a rare resource, unknown on Earth, but relatively common on Mars, a key ingredient in the particle beam weapons program. Exactly what it was and how it was used was classified information; it wasn't even listed in most reference works, but it was known that the Northern Bloc's space-based weapons system depended on it. The stuff was more valuable than diamonds and as long as the war continued, miners would be needed to wrest it from the Martian soil.

Since we don't actually see any particle weapons in use, it's hard to square this with the film's continuity.

Answer (score -1):

Turbinium made it possible to terraform in a matter of minutes, what
 would have taken otherwise a few thousand years at least

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: This seems to only relate to the *end sequence* of Total Recall.

Answer (score -3):

The Atomic Number of Turbinium is 119, and the word "Turbo" derives from the Greek word Τύρβη (turvi), meaning 'turbulence'. Turbinium is only used in Reactors through which the flow of the penetrating fluid has a Reynolds number greater than 2300 (Re ≥ 2300). This chunk of information derives from the acassic files.

Comment: I can't find any "acasdic files". Are you referring to "Akashic"?

Comment: This appears to be nonsense/technobabble. Can you offer any evidence of this?